# How can I get git log to print only the initials of author names?

Tags: git, git-log

Is there anyway I can call a function from inside the argument of 
 `git log`'s `--format` flag? Something like the following:

```
git log --graph --format "${%ani:0:4}"
```

(this isn't a real function, but you get the idea).

More specifically, I'd like to trim down the committer name (ideally, to just his/her initials) so that my graph log doesn't get too wide. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't use a command substitution in the argument of `--format`, but you can pipe the output of `git log` to `sed`/`awk` for post-processing. What output do you want to get, exactly? The initials of the commit authors?

Comment: I should have waited for clarification before posting my answer... I don't think you can do that with `--graph` on.

Comment: Well I feel like you didn't have to delete the answer, if its not possible, I think your answer was the closest thing to at least a stepping stone...

Comment: Sadly, if you use `--graph`, my now deleted answer doesn't apply at all.

Comment: Should be a way to retrain the `--graph` with `sed / awk` right ? I smell a challenge...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those two contributors:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%an"
*   Vlastimil Ovčáčík
|\
| * Willem D'Haeseleer
| * Willem D'Haeseleer
|/
* Vlastimil Ovčáčík
```

You could display first author's initial like this:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%<(3,trunc)%an%x08%x08"
*   V
|\
| * W
| * W
|/
* V
```

This answers your question just 50% and is not very practical, I know.

It works by printing the first 3 letters of author's name; if longer, the name is truncated to fit the specified limit and last two characters are replaced with `..` to signify the truncation. So only one letter from the name is printed. The two dots are then removed by typing backspace twice `%x08%x08` (`%x00` and `U+0008`).

I personally like to use the initial 4 letter of the authors' names

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%<(6,trunc)%an%x08%x08"
*   Vlas
|\
| * Will
| * Will
|/
* Vlas
```

If you insisted on two letters, I would probably "hash" together the name `%an` and the username from email his/her email address `%al`.

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%<(3,trunc)%an%x08%x08%<(3,trunc)%al%x08%x08"
*   Vx
|\
| * Wy
| * Wy
|/
* Vx
```

*(x,y are placeholders for the first letters of our email addresses)*

---

If you really wanted to display the proper initials, I think it would be possible by manually remapping the authors' names in the `.mailmap` file. Also see `%aN`.